# ion-scroll shows scroll bar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to hide the scroll bar on my `ion-scroll` I have tried everything and can not get it to go away. Can someone please help me with this? I have tried all the attributes and i have also used css like `::-webkit-scrollbar` and setting it to `display: none;`. That hides it in the browser just fine but when I look at it on an emulator or my physical iPhone it still shows. Here is my `ion-scroll`.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollbar-x="false" id="contests-filter">
  <ion-row nowrap class="app-padding">
    <div *ngFor="let name of filterNames;">
      <ion-chip>
        <ion-label>{{ name }}</ion-label>
      </ion-chip>
    </div>
  </ion-row>
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [overflow-y: auto;] OR  [overflow-x: hidden] in the CSS.